# Creating a timer from xml time

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

i've extracted a time from an XML and put it in to a listview but i want it to count down. Having 0 luck with how to do this.

here is my code for getting the time & some pictures;

```
Private void ListViewTrainingQue()
    {

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        string string2 = "https://api.eveonline.com/char/SkillQueue.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH";



        // Add Columns to listview 
        listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 50);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Level", 50);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Remaing Time", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Bar", 100);

        // string array1 = "2015-10-23 13:00";



        // Create Array to return values to. 
        string[] arr = new string[3];
        ListViewItem item;

       XmlDocument XMLtrans = new XmlDocument();
       XMLtrans.Load(string2);
       XmlNodeList TRnodelist = XMLtrans.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/rowset/row");
        foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in TRnodelist)
        {                                 
            string array1 = xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"].InnerText;
            var date = DateTime.Parse(array1);
            var Timespan = date - DateTime.Now;

            if (xmlnode.Attributes["typeID"] != null)
                arr[0] =  xmlnode.Attributes["typeID"].InnerText;
            if (xmlnode.Attributes["level"] != null)
                 arr[1] = xmlnode.Attributes["level"].InnerText;
            if (xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"] != null)
                arr[2] = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s", Timespan.Hours, Timespan.Minutes, Timespan.Seconds);

            item = new ListViewItem(arr);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Here is how it looks;

[image]

Comment: Voting to close.  "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. "

Comment: so you want me to add an example of a failed attempt? i can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the `ListViewItem` set the extracted `DateTime` as `Tag` of `item`:

```
item = new ListViewItem(arr);
item.Tag= date;
```

Then add a timer to your form and set `Interval` to `1000` and make its `Enabled` to `true` and handle `Tick` event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        var timeSpan = ((DateTime)item.Tag) - DateTime.Now;
        item.SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s",
             timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, ! just still not working getting an error; {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: This is the main idea and you will solve the problem this way.

Comment: Where you get Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: var timeSpan = ((DateTime)item.Tag) - DateTime.Now; <-- this line

Comment: this means you have forgotten to set the `Tag` in `ListViewTrainingQue`. You should set the `Tag` in the loop that creates item `item.Tag= date;`

Comment: i see! ok leave it with me i shall take it from here, if i get any probs i'll be bacl :D cheers mate. learning is fun.

Comment: Let me know what's the problem and what error you receive?

Comment: still the same issue as abouv

Comment: Have you got the main idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94943/discussion-between-reza-aghaei-and-losec).

Comment: Hi Having a little trouble with making only the first cell tick

Comment: Hi, You should get the main idea then you should learn how to work with `Timer` and then you should learn how to work with `ListView`. **The main idea:** Having a timer that setting it to raise `Tick` event every 1000 millisecond and put your logic in the event handler. **About the `Timer`:**  use `Interval` property to set the interval of raising the `Tick` event. you can also `Stop()` or `Start()` it when you need. **About the the `ListView`:** You can find items using `Items` property for example `listView1.Items[0]` is the first item. To find items count `listView`.Items.Count`

Comment: To get sub items of an item: `listView1.Items[0].SubItems[0]`, to remove an item at a position `listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0)` or to remove an specific item `listView1.Items.Remove(item)`